# Why Fibonacci(prime-1) or Fibonacci(prime+1) is divisible by that prime?

Tags: prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers

Why Fibonacci(prime-1) or Fibonacci(prime+1) is divisible by that prime and Fibonacci(nonprime-1) or Fibonacci(nonprime+1) is not divisible by that nonprime?

Is there any elegant proof of that?

Comment: The prime 5 do not satisfy that.

Comment: Have a look to see whether http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37955/prime-appearances-in-fibonacci-number-factorizations answers your question (but be prepared for some Algebraic Number Theory).

Comment: @GerryMyerson Use *Mathematica* brute force to $10000$ and already found many counter-examples. These are `{1, 323, 377, 442, 1891, 2737, 2834, 3827, 4181, 5777, 6479, 6601, 6721, 8149}` (for being composite). Yet brute force to 5000 and the statement still true for primes.

Comment: @user, counterexamples to the statements on nonprimes, right? The statement about primes is discussed in the link I gave.

Comment: @user, the numbers you are finding are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A182554

Comment: In the oeis page, it said `It is known that for prime p <> 5, Fibonacci(p-1) or Fibonacci(p+1) is divisible by p.` And https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Primality_testing also said that. So you can find information.

Answer (score 3):

This is an extended comment, not an answer.  The answer of user153012 to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1086066/3736) provides a link to a paper where your statement (which holds for primes other than $5$) is proved.  I also have an answer to that question, which, while not providing a proof of your statement, does suggest a generalization to composite numbers not divisible by $5$.  I do not, at the moment, have a proof of the generalization.

First observe that, for prime $p\ne5$, not only is one of $F_{p-1}$ and $F_{p+1}$ divisible by $p$, but the other is congruent to $1$ mod $p$.  Together, these statements imply that $F_{p+1}+F_{p-1}-1$ is divisible by $p$ which also holds when $p=5$.  This is one of the statements of which the linked question asked for a proof.

Furthermore, we can say which of $F_{p-1}$ and $F_{p+1}$ is divisible by $p$ and which is congruent to $1$ mod $p$: if $\left(\frac{p}{5}\right)=1$, then $p\mid (F_{p+1}-1)$ and $p\mid F_{p-1}$; if $\left(\frac{p}{5}\right)=-1$, then $p\mid F_{p+1}$ and $p\mid(F_{p-1}-1)$.  Recall the definition of the Legendre symbol, for $q$ a prime: $$\left(\frac{a}{q}\right)=\begin{cases}0 & \text{if $q\mid a$,}\\ 1 & \text{if $a$ is a square mod $q$,}\\ -1 & \text{if $a$ is a nonsquare mod $q$.}\end{cases}
$$
Therefore in our case, $p\mid F_{p+1},\ F_{p-1}-1$ when $p\equiv1,\ 4$ mod $5$, while $p\mid F_{p+1}-1,\ F_{p-1}$ when $p\equiv2,\ 3$ mod $5$.  For example, when $p=19$, $p\equiv4$ mod $5$, so $19\mid (F_{20}-1),\ F_{18}$.  Indeed $F_{20}=6765=1+356\cdot19$ and  $F_{18}=2584=136\cdot19$.

Since $F_{1-(1/5)}=F_0=0$ and $F_{1+(1/5)}=F_2=1$, we can write the observations above more compactly as
$$
\begin{aligned}
p&\mid\left(F_{p+(p\vert5)}-F_{1+(1\vert5)}\right)\\
p&\mid\left(F_{p-(p\vert5)}-F_{1-(1\vert5)}\right),
\end{aligned}\tag{1}
$$
where, again, $(a\vert q)$ represents the Legendre symbol.  Now in my answer to the linked question, I prove by a combinatorial argument that, for any natural number $n$,
$$
n\mid \sum_{d\mid n}\mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)(F_{d+1}+F_{d-1}),
$$
where $\mu(j)$ is the Möbius function.  This suggests that, just as the prime version $p\mid\left((F_{p+1}+F_{p-1})-(F_2+F_0)\right)$ can be broken apart into the two conditions in (1), it may be possible to break apart the condition for general $n$.  Indeed, it appears that when $5\not\mid n$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
n&\mid\sum_{d\mid n}\mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)F_{d+(d\vert5)}\\
n&\mid\sum_{d\mid n}\mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)F_{d-(d\vert5)}.
\end{aligned}\tag{2}
$$
I've checked this is true for the first few hundred $n$ not divisible by $5$, but do not have a proof.  Here's an example: the divisors of $12$ are $1,\ 2,\ 3,\ 4,\ 6,\ 12$ and we have $\mu(12/1)=0$, $\mu(12/2)=1$, $\mu(12/3)=0$, $\mu(12/4)=-1$, $\mu(12/6)=-1$, $\mu(12/12)=1$ and $\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)=1$, $\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)=-1$, $\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)=-1$, $\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)=1$, $\left(\frac{6}{5}\right)=1$, $\left(\frac{12}{5}\right)=-1$.  Hence if the condition is true then we should have
$$
\begin{aligned}
&12 \mid (F_{12-1}-F_{6+1}-F_{4+1}+F_{2-1})=(89-13-5+1)=72\\
&12 \mid (F_{12+1}-F_{6-1}-F_{4-1}+F_{2+1})=(233-5-2+2)=228,
\end{aligned}
$$
which do indeed hold.