# Divisibility of Lucas+Fibonacci

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, lucas-numbers

I was playing around with the Fibonacci sequence and the Lucas sequence, and I noticed something.

It seems that for most $n\in\mathbb{N}$ where $n|(F_n+L_n)$, $n$ is prime and is congruent to 3 or 7 modulo 10. As far as I can tell, no primes that are congruent to 1 or 9 modulo 10 fit this description.

For example, for primes ending in 3 or 7:

- $F_{13}+L_{13}=233+521=754=13\cdot58$
- $F_{17}+L_{17}=1597+3571=5168=17\cdot304$
- $F_{37}+L_{37}=24157817+54018521=78176338=37\cdot2112874$
- $F_{83}+L_{83}=99194853094755497+221806434537978679=321001287632734176=83\cdot3867485393165472$

And for good measure, here are a few primes ending in 1 or 9 (that don't divide the aforementioned sum):

- $F_{11}+L_{11}=89+199=288=2^5\cdot3^2$
- $F_{19}+L_{19}=4181+9349=13530=2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot11\cdot41$
- $F_{29}+L_{29}=514229+1149851=1664080=2^4\cdot5\cdot11\cdot31\cdot61$

Is this an actual pattern, and if so, is there a reason for it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Fibonacci(prime-1) or Fibonacci(prime+1) is divisible by that prime?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1801885/why-fibonacciprime-1-or-fibonacciprime1-is-divisible-by-that-prime) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24p%5Cmid%20F_%7Bp%2B1%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aprime%2C%20OR%20content%3AFibonacci&p=1). Note from [Lucas number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number#Relationship_to_Fibonacci_numbers), we have $L_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n+1}$. Thus, $F_n+L_n=F_n+F_{n-1}+F_{n+1}=2F_{n+1}$. Thus, we're ...

Comment: (cont.) looking for cases of $p \gt 2$ and $p \neq 5$ where $p\mid F_{p+1}$. The duplicate shows this occurs only for where $p \equiv 2,3 \pmod{5}$, i.e., $p \equiv 3,7 \pmod{10}$. Also, FYI, that proposed duplicate has a [comment](/questions/1801885/why-fibonacciprime-1-or-fibonacciprime1-is-divisible-by-that-prime?noredirect=1#comment3679877_1801885) linking to [Fibonacci primality testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Primality_testing). Finally, it also links to [Prove Divisibility In Fibonacci Sequence Over A Prime Number](/q/1086066), which has some more useful info.